# pandas series sort_index() not working with kind='mergesort'

Tags: sorting, pandas, indexing, mergesort

I needed a stable index sorting for DataFrames, when I had this problem:

In cases where a DataFrame becomes a Series (when only a single column matches the selection), the kind argument returns an error. See example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.Series(range(10))
df_b = pd.Series(range(100, 110))
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
df.sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

with the following error:

```
----> 6 df.sort_index(kind='mergesort')

TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'
```

If DataFrames (more then one column is selected), mergesort works ok.

**EDIT:**

When selecting a single column from a DataFrame for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(25)).reshape(5,5))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(100, 125)).reshape(5,5))
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
```

the following returns an error:

```
df[0].sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

...since the selection is casted to a pandas Series, and as pointed out the [pandas.Series.sort_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) documentation contains a bug.

However,

```
df[[0]].sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```

works alright, since its type continues to be a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.Series.sort_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) has **no** `kind` parameter.

here is the definition of this function for Pandas 0.18.1 (file: `./pandas/core/series.py`):

```
# line 1729
@Appender(generic._shared_docs['sort_index'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)
def sort_index(self, axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False,
               sort_remaining=True):

    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
    index = self.index
    if level is not None:
        new_index, indexer = index.sortlevel(level, ascending=ascending,
                                             sort_remaining=sort_remaining)
    elif isinstance(index, MultiIndex):
        from pandas.core.groupby import _lexsort_indexer
        indexer = _lexsort_indexer(index.labels, orders=ascending)
        indexer = com._ensure_platform_int(indexer)
        new_index = index.take(indexer)
    else:
        new_index, indexer = index.sort_values(return_indexer=True,
                                               ascending=ascending)

    new_values = self._values.take(indexer)
    result = self._constructor(new_values, index=new_index)

    if inplace:
        self._update_inplace(result)
    else:
        return result.__finalize__(self)
```

file `./pandas/core/generic.py`, line 39

```
_shared_doc_kwargs = dict(axes='keywords for axes', klass='NDFrame',
                          axes_single_arg='int or labels for object',
                          args_transpose='axes to permute (int or label for'
                          ' object)')
```

So most probably it's a bug in the pandas documentation...

Your `df` is Series, it's **not** a  data frame

Comment: yes, i know. I needed a general sort_index that worked for both DataFrames and Series and that was stable. Thanks!

Comment: @HNMusac, why do you want to specify `kind='mergesort'` parameter explicitly?

Comment: The default 'quicksort' is not stable! It may change the original order of entries with the same key. Thanks!

Comment: @HNMusac, what about this workaround for Series: `s.to_frame().sort_index(kind='mergesort')`

Comment: definitely works too!! But `df[cols].sort_index(kind='mergesort')` generalizes better for example when `cols = [0]` or `cols=[0,1]`. Thanks!!